# What is the data type of vptr?

Tags: c++

Any class having a virtual function would get an extra hidden pointer which would point to the most derived class.

What is the type of this vptr?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It has no type. It's an implementation detail unspecified by the standard; *it is not part of the language*.

Note that C++ doesn't say that there has to be a virtual table or a virtual "pointer" at all (though this is the most common implementation of RTTI in C++ toolchains).

Also, your analysis is wrong. In, say, GCC, usually each *object* gets a vptr that points to the relevant virtual table for that object's type: object has pointer, type has table.

Comment: Aww, your answer is no fun :(

Comment: @Blindy: At least it's not completely misleading.

Comment: Hi
According to my understanding vtable is formed at class level.
As you are saying that " In GCC, usually each object gets a vptr that points to the relevant virtual table for that object's type: object has pointer, type has table". 
If each object is getting its own vptr and all pointing to same vtable then what is the need of creating different vptr pointers. We can create a static class level vptr.

Comment: @Sambav: No, you can't, because access to your objects is not always performed through its static type. Consider `A* ptr = new B(); ptr->foo()` -- the only way for `B::foo` to be invoked here is that the type `B` contains a hidden pointer to the vtable for `B`, as opposed to the vtable for `A`. This is called _polymorphism_.

Answer (score 2):

The standard does not guarantee the presence of the virtual table pointer, even though most implementations use it.

As a result, it has no type. It is simply an array of pointers.

Comment: It's not an array of pointers either. It has no representation in terms of C++ constructs.

Answer (score 2):

It has compiler-dependent type which may be anything as long as the compiler understands it. As the language doesn't say anything about `vptr`, neither programmers use it in their code, compilers are free to create any *arbitrary type* for implementing runtime polymorphism. That *type* doesn't has to be conformant with the C++ language.